# Localization in ASP.net - Keep Curency as $ instead of €

Tags: asp.net, localization, currency

I am doing that but if the language is Spanish, this is being displayed 475,00 €

The client wants it so that it is actually $ 475.00

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is formatted according to the [CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx). You can specify the culture explicitly by passing a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) to `Format`, for example US English:

```
<%#String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:c}", Eval("Subtotal"))%>
```

To set the culture globally so you don't have to specify it each time, you can change the [CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx):

```
Thread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the first approach of setting the format in one place minimizes changes right now. Is there something that can be done in one place? Secondly, I tried copying the code directly...it doesn't understand CultureInfo..am I missing something?

Comment: CultureInfo is in the System.Globalization namespace which you probably need to import. See my edited answer regarding change in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a CultureInfo that uses "$" as the currency symbol, then pass it as the first parameter to String.Format.

Comment: NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol = "$"; which changes the symbol but it appends it to the end? instead of $ 475.